# Booting Fedora 23 after installation fails

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I just installed the Fedora 23 from the official iso.
Installation succeed and computer reboot.

But Fedora starting to load (just after grub selection) it write on my screen upper the loading bar:

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked
>
> See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

So, I tried to restart on rescue mode and set a password to root (which unlock root account). But I still have this error.

Any suggestion to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from rescue mode, I found that I had about 200 updates to do. Applied it, restarted and now it work like a charm ^^